# WAMP: Index.php executes/runs immediately when selecting the directory it is in

Tags: php, wamp

I had a little, slightly annoying problem that was an easy fix but I didn't understand why it took place.

I have a several folders in ../wamp/www/- and in one of them I had a file, that I had created, named index.php. When I clicked on the other directories I could browse through the normal list where I saw all the files, but when I opened the folder where the file Index.php was it executed immediately and I never saw what was in the folder. Instead I had to manually change the url to open other files in that directory.

I deleted index.php and half expected it to run some other .php-file in that directory, but didn't.

I'm aware of that there is a index.php-file in the www-directory (the comments in French though), which clearly is part of the WAMP system I downloaded, but having seen tutorials where people use index.php I'd have expected someone to mention this potential problem.

Comment: If i understood the question wight , please go through this [link](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) . if that doesn't help kindly update me so that i can be more specific in answering

Comment: You could try to set `DirectoryIndex disabled` (via htaccess or vhost i.e.), check [apache wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) and [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) for more info

Comment: Hi! I will try to check out both answers and test them. Right now, after having looked at the sources and at some documentation I realize that this is perhaps something I really don't get at my super-beginner-level. I've saved a directory with a index.php-file where this problem occurs and I'll get back to it when I am more knowledgeable about the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not a problem!**

***This is how web servers work.***

To be specific there is a setting in the Apache config that tells Apache the names of files that it should run **Automatically** if no actual file is specified in the URL

Specifically this line in `httpd.conf`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
```

It is normal that a web server will run any of these files if it sees them when only the directory is specified on a URL.

And before you consider changing it, **dont**. Almost everything you will come accross EXPECTS this to be the case.